# GCP Autoscaling PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, migration, autoscaling

I have an app that spikes postgresql queries at evening (over 80% CPU usage), and has very few the rest of the day (< 20% usage). I want this machine to autoscale when it queries PostgreSQL, instead of getting scared we will hit CPU limits. I have two questions.

1. When we hit 100%, do requests get delayed?
2. Is there an autoscaling PostgreSQL? It seems there's one on AWS but I don't know how to move from GCP to AWS easily without downtime...

Answer (score 2):

1- Yes, When CPU usage hits 100%, The requests will be delayed.
2- Autoscaling for storage is [set up by default](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/instance-settings#automatic-storage-increase-2ndgen) but there is no autoscaling feature for cores and memory.

[Autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) works by adding more VMs to your Managed instance groups when there is more load, and deleting VMs when the need for VMs is lowered.

You can set up the [alert policy in Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/) to get notified when an instance is reaching peak usage and then make changes manually.

You can also [create a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) for autoscaling and present your use case here to have Engineering potentially look into implementing it.